# Solve $f(n)=\begin{cases} n-3 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \qquad{\text{if $n\ge1000$}}\\ f\big(f(n+5)\big)\quad{\text{if $n<1000$}} \end{cases}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Suppose I have a function $f(n)$ below, find $f(84)$ :
$$f(n)=\begin{cases}
n-3 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \qquad{\text{if $n\ge1000$}}\\
f\big(f(n+5)\big)\quad{\text{if $n<1000$}}
\end{cases}$$
My attempt:
$$\begin{align}
f(84)=&f\big(f(89)\big)\\
f(89)=&f\big(f(94)\big)\\
f(94)=&f\big(f(99)\big)\\
&\vdots\\
f(999)=&f\big(f(1004)\big)\\
f(1004)=&1001
\end{align}
$$
Now:
$$\begin{align}
f(999)&=f(1001)=998\\
f(994)&=f\big(f(999)\big)=f(998)\Rightarrow
f(998)=f\big(f(1003)\big)=f(1000)=997\\
&f(994)=f(998)=997\\
f(989)&=f\big(f(994)\big)=f(997)\Rightarrow f(997)=f\big(f(1002)\big)=f(999)=998\\
&f(989)=f(997)=998\\
f(984)&=f\big(f(989)\big)=f(998)=997\\
f(979)&=f\big(f(984)\big)=f(997)=998\\
\vdots
&&
\end{align}$$
Obviously since it the value of $f(n)$ alternates between $997$ & $998$, depending on whether $n$ is odd or even, thus:
$$\vdots\\
f(89)=998\\
\therefore\bbox[10px, border:1px solid black]{f(84)=997}\\
$$

My question: is there a more efficient way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $f^{h} = f(f(\cdots f(f(x))\cdots))$, where the function $f$ is performed $h$ times. We find that $f(84) = f(f(89)) = f^2(89) = f^3(94) = \ldots f^{y}(1004)$. $1004 = 84 + 5(y - 1) \Longrightarrow y = 185$. So we now need to reduce $f^{185}(1004)$.

Let’s write out a couple more iterations of this function: \begin{align*}f^{185}(1004)&=f^{184}(1001)=f^{183}(998)=f^{184}(1003)=f^{183}(1000)\\ &=f^{182}(997)=f^{183}(1002)=f^{182}(999)=f^{183}(1004)\end{align*} So this function reiterates with a period of 2 for $x$. On first thought it might seem that $f(1004) = 1001$ is the answer; however, that is not true since the solution occurs slightly before that. Start at $f^3(1004)$: $f^{3}(1004)=f^{2}(1001)=f(998)=f^{2}(1003)=f(1000)=\boxed{997}$